# Reset root password for Chromebook

Tags: google-chrome-os, chromebook

How could I do this?

I tried:

1. putting the chromebook in dev mode
2. enabling debugging options
3. set the root password
4. browse as guest(also tried with a google account)
5. open shell ctrl + shift + t
6. enter `shell` and `sudo su`
7. enter password I set in debugging options window

Password is incorrect.

I tried also to recovering with [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromebook-recovery-utili/jndclpdbaamdhonoechobihbbiimdgai?hl=en), and after that normal mode was set again. Then I went back to development mode, did the same steps above. Getting the same result.

Any advice?

Comment: did you try just doing `sudo su` after logging into your Google account from within the Linux terminal?

Answer (score 14):

Starting from the desktop, logged in as a user[1], the following steps have solved this problem for me:

1. Press Ctrl+Alt+Forward Arrow (Ctrl+Alt+F2 on some machines. If your machine doesn't have F2, then try whichever key is two spaces to the right of Esc - typically it's an arrow facing to the right).
2. You should reach a "Developer Console" prompt, where the last line of text ends with `localhost login:`. Enter "root" and hit return.
3. Enter the root password you set previously (or just hit return if you didn't set a root password).

[1] It may be possible to reach this console without being logged in - I am not sure.

Comment: Strangely, the empty password for the root user does not work for me on VT2.  I can type 'chronos' at the login prompt and the password I had set for it, and it works, but not for 'root'.  Once I'm logged in as 'chronos', I do 'sudo su', type the chronos password, and I'm root.  I try to change the root password with passwd, and it tells me 'Authentication token lock busy'.

Comment: Good answer: it is required to a the text console (Ctrl-Alt-Fx) *the first time* because the chronos user doesn't have any password initially, meaning `sudo` doesn't work until chromeos-setdevpasswd has been used at least once.

Answer (score 1):

I just spent several hours trying to figure this out. In particular, Ctrl-Alt-F2 (AKA '->') was only showing me a blank, black screen. However, it turned out that there was still a login prompt running (just not showing on the screen)!

I was able to log in as root and run the 'chromeos-setdevpasswd' command to set a password, just by blindly pressing the right keys and hoping it would work. It did!

I didn't see this possibility mentioned in any of my search results, so thought I'd put it here in case it helps anyone. I'm using an Asus C202S Chromebook, with `CHROMEOS_RELEASE_VERSION=10895.56.0` (according to `/etc/lsb-release`)

Answer (score 1):

1.) localhost login: root
password: The password is the password you set for enabling debugging features.

For Example: If your password that you set is: 12345678 then it will look like...

```
localhost login: root
password:12345678
```

2.) Now it should say: localhost ~ # 
enter chromeos-setdevpasswd and press enter it will look like...

```
localhost ~ # chromeos-setdevpasswd
password:
```

now enter a password to use for sudo su. Then verify your password.

Answer (score -1):

I found this to set up root password for chronos. [Android App Testing on Chromebooks
February 28, 2019](https://blog.secureideas.com/2019/02/android-app-testing-on-chromebooks.html)

Need to start from "setting up developer mode initial reboot".

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.